# timestamp in excel based on previous cell entry in two columns

Tags: excel, vba

I need this code to do the same thing with column 3. The code pastes a timestamp in a cell when there is an entry made in a previous cell. I need the code to do so in columns 3 and 5. I tried making it but I kept getting errors that would only allow me to do one or the other.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
    On Error GoTo Handler 
    If Target.Column = 5 And Target.Value <> "" Then 
        Application.EnableEvents = False 
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss") 
        Application.EnableEvents = True 
    End If 
Handler: 
End Sub
```

Comment: Try including the error message that you received. It will likely be easier to help you with that info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have only just started learning VBA in the past week so I'm sure someone will come along and post a more efficient way but this seems to work...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo Handler
If Target.Column = 3 And Target.Value <> "" Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Offset(0, 1) = Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

If Target.Column = 5 And Target.Value <> "" Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Offset(0, 1) = Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

Handler:
End Sub
```

I've just come across this also [Create an automatic date stamp in excel from an entry](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2800030/11390575)